# Can't connect to the server at this time. Your table cannot be published in Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel Sheet. As per my requirement, I have to import this Excel sheet into SharePoint Online List.

When I tried to import that Excel Sheet into SharePoint Online List, It is showing an error after providing the SharePoint Site URL and Name.

The error is appearing as "Can't connect to the server at this time. your table cannot be published". You can refer the below screenshot:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTkKN.png)

Note: I am using Google Chrome. Also, I tried in IE Browser, But the same issue is appearing everywhere.

I have Full control permission to the SharePoint List and also do not have any issue in IE certificate security Setting.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can resolve this issue? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Are you able to create a Sharepoint list from the Sharepoint interface and add data to it manually?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Yes...I can able to create SharePoint List from the SharePoint interface. Also I can add data to it manually.

Comment: Seems there are a few things you can try listed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d0c56feb-13cd-4ffe-9706-852fbd877fa3/cant-connect-to-the-server-at-this-time-your-table-cannot-be-published?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: When you click "Next" on the export page, you may be asked to enter your Microsoft 365 credentials. Please make sure that the account you entered is an account with permissions

Comment: No..it's not asking Microsoft 365 credentials. When I am clicking Next, it's directly appearing that error.

Comment: This should be caused by the wrong account you used to connect to SharePoint site. 
Sign out of your logged-in account and log back in (Use an account that has permission on SharePoint site).